# Reading comma separated data from string into struct, ignoring certain fields

Tags: c++, parsing, struct, stream

About the data:

- Fields are separated by comma ','
- It is always a certain number of fields (in my case 33)
- Fields are always in the same order
- The data is of different types, represented in ASCII. The types are known to me
- Some fields are always empty, and some are always to be ignored (not useful data)

Example of data:

```
AnIdentifier,1,G,2014-10-01,11:00,,,3,7555,1,14535,1 .. etc
```

I am wondering what is the best way to read this data into a struct, in a C++ way. I used sscanf earlier, but I thought the format-parameter of the call got rather big and messy.

I also tried splitting the string into tokens in a vector, before setting the values in the struct one by one with values from the vector, but then I didn't have the nice automatic data conversion.

I saw an example of overloading the >> operator in the struct:

```
struct MyDataStruct
{
    std::string Id;
    char D;
    char S;
    std::string Date; // Preferably these could be combined
    std::string Time; // to a time_t?
    bool Running;
    int Runtime;
    ...
    ...

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, MyDataStruct &ds) { 
        return is >> Id >> D >> S >> Date >> Time >> Running >> Runtime ...
    }
}
```

My C++ knowledge is limited (used to C#), so I started to struggle when there were fields I wanted to ignore while reading into the struct. Say there are 5 fields in `is` after reading into `Time` that I wish to skip before reading into `Running`.

And say I wished to represent the timestamp by a time_t instead of the two strings `Date` and `Time` (the way they are represented in the received data), could this be accomplished directly in the operator overload while reading into the struct?

Comment: Instead of trying to use the input operator `>>` to read the fields, I recommend you [read a whole line](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) then tokenize it (can also be done with `std::getline`) using the comma as separator. This way you can easily parse each field in whichever way you want.

Comment: That sounds similar to what I mentioned, about the tokens in a vector (`std::vector<std::string>`). This is viable, but I liked the way the input operator works with the conversion of data from strings.